# Understanding difference between P2P-client and P2P-device

Tags: linux, wifi

I'm going through WiFi direct, learning about it and how to set it up on linux. I've ran `iw list` to see what my wireless card supports, and this is what I get.

```
        Supported interface modes:
                 * managed
                 * AP
                 * AP/VLAN
                 * monitor
                 * mesh point
                 * P2P-client
                 * P2P-GO
                 * P2P-device
```

...

```
valid interface combinations:
                 * #{ managed } <= 2, #{ AP, mesh point, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
                   total <= 3, #channels <= 2
```

What I'm managed to find is that `P2P-GO` means it supports `Group Owner` mode and `P2P-client` mode would be the device to connect to the Group Owner. What I cannot find is what `P2P-device` refers to. What is the difference between `P2P-device` and `P2P-client`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](https://hsc.com/DesktopModules/DigArticle/Print.aspx?PortalId=0&ModuleId=1215&Article=221) may help. There it explains some of the terminology as well as a whole host of details on peer to peer wifi:

> Wi-Fi Direct devices, formally known as P2P Devices, communicate by establishing P2P Groups, which are functionally equivalent to traditional Wi-Fi infrastructure networks. The device implementing AP like functionality in the P2P Group is referred to as the P2P Group Owner (P2P GO), and devices acting as clients are known as P2P Clients.

I read this to mean that both sides are "devices" and they then both assume a role, either "client" or "GO", but there is a lot more information on that page.

Comment: I found this, which seems to confirm your thought on the meaning of 'device'. https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/linville/wireless.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/nl80211.h?id=HEAD#n2118